# How to rename firebase functions in nuxt 3 using nitro?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, nuxt.js, nitro, nuxt3

Here's my nuxt.config.js

```js
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  preset: 'node-server',
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
  ],
  nitro: {
    preset: 'firebase',
  },
  srcDir: './src',
});
```

I want to change the functions name which is server by default to something else. There seems no option in nitro or nuxt config to do that.

In the .output/server/index.mjs in line 4, the default export name is server

```js
// line 4
export { s as server } from './chunks/nitro/firebase.mjs';
```

Comment: Did you mean rename the name of the Firebase function both in Firebase console and your code repo ? Because you can rename the Firebase functions as shown in this [documentations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#modify-name)

Comment: Yes, but this method requires making a new copy of the function and then deleting the old one. It's not "rename" per se but replace. What I want is to change the name `server` via config when I build the app. Not after the fact coz I am deploying using CI so I can't do manual renaming. @RohitKharche

Comment: can you provide recreation steps for your setup because I am still on nuxt 2, you can try adding `functionsName: 'server'` property in your `nuxt.config.js`

Comment: Thanks for this @RohitKharche. Where exactly in `nuxt.config.js` coz I didn't see anything regarding this option in the docs. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just BTW I am having the same problem I think. I want to deploy multiple nuxt3 apps on firebase hosting as websites under one common project. But I need one "server" function to be setup for each nuxt app. Supposedly with a unique name to match with my hosting config.
Now the "server" cloud-function is overwritten each time I deploy any nuxt hosting.
@jofftiquez is that the same problem you are trying to solve?

I was able to change the function name patching the output/server/index.mjs file generated by the build comand (actually I use a predeploy script with regex to do that):
from

`export { s as server } from './chunks/nitro/firebase.mjs'`

to

`export { s as custom-server-name } from './chunks/nitro/firebase.mjs'`

then in firebase.json I configured my custom function name:

```
  "functions": {
    "source": ".output/server",
    "runtime": "nodejs16"
  },
  "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "dev",
      "public": ".output/public",
      "cleanUrls": true,
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "function": "custom-server-name"
        }
      ]
    },
```

And I was able to deploy the function "custom-server-name" with:

`firebase deploy --only functions:custom-server-name --project=default`

It's the only approach I found so far.
You can investigate in the `codebase` key under the `functions` in firebase.json. If you deploy from seperate repos it's usefull.

my script stub:

```js
//something like that...
import { readFile, readFileSync, writeFileSync } from 'node:fs'

const env = process.env
// Read deployment config from firebase.json and extract custom function name
const firebaseJSON = JSON.parse(readFileSync('firebase.json'))

//... I extract the rewrites server name from firebase.json based on the target name I extract from env variables

// Read file into a string
readFile('.output/server/index.mjs', 'utf-8', (errRead, contents) => {
  if (errRead) {
    return console.error(errRead)
  }
  console.log('Found index.mjs file contents: ', contents)

  const updated = contents.replace(
    /{ s as server }/gi,
    `{ s as ${serverFunctionName} }`
  )

  // Write back to file
  console.log(
    `Replacing nuxt server function name with':  '${serverFunctionName}'`
  )
  writeFileSync('.output/server/index.mjs', updated, 'utf-8', (errWrite) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  })
```

Currently I moved the script above into my pipeline script and run it before `firebase deploy`

The `function: predeploy` key in firebase.json or any manual command calling the script should do it as well. Depends on your setup.

Comment: Hello, yes, that's precisely what I wanna do. I wanna deploy multiple nuxt app in one firebase project so I want each function to have different names from each other. 

May I see how did you do it with script?